# Substring Method

Tags: java

I had to write this program to output the first letter of a first name and the first five letters of the last name plus a random number from 10-99. It works but I thought that the substring method starts at 0 and goes from there so that substring(0,0) would include just the first letter and likewise substring(0,4) would include 0 1 2 3 4 letters for the first 5. Or does it not include the final number in the output?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class NameModifier
{

public static void main (String[] args)
    {

    String namefirst;
    String namelast;
    Random generator = new Random();
    int num;

    num = generator.nextInt(99) + 10;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    //prompts user
    System.out.print ("Enter your first name: ");
    namefirst = scan.nextLine();    
    System.out.print ("Enter your last name: ");    
    namelast = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Your entered: " + namefirst + " " + namelast);

    //outputs modified username possibility
    System.out.println("Here is a random username for you: ");
    System.out.print (namefirst.substring(0, 1));
    System.out.print (namelast.substring(0,5));
    System.out.print (num);

    scan.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope you can better understand with this example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Java's substring inputs,

```
public String substring(int beginIndex,int endIndex)

beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive.
endIndex - the ending index, exclusive.
```

Note the exclusive. substring(0,1) will return a string including character 0, up to but NOT including character 1.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int)

Comment: @Lou44  One way to help remember this behavior is that `substring()` works like the _typical_ for-next loop, which stops _one short_ of the final number.  _e.g._  `for (int i=1; i<myArray.length; i++)` stops 1 before myArray.length.